# Memory management of a CFErrorRef returned by ABRecordSetValue

Tags: objective-c, c, core-foundation

Consider some typical CF code involving error handling, say something like this:

```
ABRecordRef aRecord = ABPersonCreate();
CFErrorRef anError = NULL;
ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, CFSTR("Joe"), &anError);
```

How do I handle `anError` after this code? Do I have to retain it, to make sure it doesn't go away, and then later release it? Or am I already the owner and I only have to release it later?

Comment: Note that `anError` in this sample will never have a value upon return. The convention here is that an error will be returned *only* if the error argument is non-null.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Core Foundation framework, it's always the caller's responsibility to release an error returned through a `CFErrorRef *` argument.  For example here's a header file comment from [`CFBundle.h`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635/CFBundle.h):

```
CF_EXPORT
Boolean CFBundlePreflightExecutable(CFBundleRef bundle, CFErrorRef *error) CF_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0);
    /* This function will return true if the bundle is loaded, or if the bundle appears to be */
    /* loadable upon inspection.  This does not mean that the bundle is definitively loadable, */
    /* since it may fail to load due to link errors or other problems not readily detectable. */
    /* If this function detects problems, it will return false, and return a CFError by reference. */
    /* It is the responsibility of the caller to release the CFError. */
```

Chances are the AB framework uses the same convention.

Comment: That comment in the header file directly contradicts [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/Reference/reference.html), which says that ownership follows the Create Rule.  The function name does not contain either of the words `Create` or `Copy`, so therefore you don't become an owner upon calling it.

Comment: I would say that mention of the create rule is unclear.  I tend to trust header files more, because the header file is more likely to be written by the engineer creating or maintaining the actual code.  Anyway, [`CFBundlePreflightExecutable` is open source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.18/CFBundle.c).  If you inspect the code, you will discover that you **do** own the returned error, regardless of how you interpret the documentation.

Comment: If you think the code should be changed to match your interpretation of the documentation, [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/).  If you think the documentation should be changed to more clearly match the code, click the “Not helpful...” link at the bottom of the documentation and let them know.

Comment: Huh, interesting.  I did click the "Not helpful..." link and left feedback, so maybe Apple will fix it (though I'm not holding my breath).  I definitely don't think that changing the source code is a good idea, since it would introduce a wealth of compatibility problems with existing code, I'm sure.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, when the docs say something follows the Create Rule, that means you should interpret it *as though* it had "Create" in its name even if it doesn't. It basically means "you receive ownership of this". If they weren't documenting exceptions to the naming conventions, then there would never be reason to call such things out in the docs (other than where the conventions were originally defined).

Comment: So has there been any update on this issue? Did anyone from Apple reply? Do we release the CFErrorRef or not? Thanks.

Comment: @platypus: See the comments above; specifically, one of rob mayoff's. You do own the returned error and consequently need to release it.

Answer (score 2):

According to "CFError.h" where CFErrorRef is defined: i.e.

```
typedef struct __CFError * CFErrorRef; // line 43 in CFError.h
```

if you scroll to the top, you will see this in line 14 to line 22:

```
CFError *error;
if (!ReadFromFile(fd, &error)) {
    ... process error ...
    CFRelease(error);   // If an error occurs, the returned CFError must be released.
}

It is the responsibility of anyone returning CFErrors this way to:
- Not touch the error argument if no error occurs
- Create and assign the error for return only if the error argument is non-NULL
```

Thus it seems like we do need to release the CFErrorRef ourselves!