# Do I need to release CFError?

Tags: ios, memory-management, core-foundation

In Core Foundation, when I call a function with a CFError pointer, am I responsible to release that error afterwards? For example:

```
CFErrorRef error = NULL;
BOOL success = ABRecordSetValue(record, property, value, &error);
if (!success) {
    // handle error
    CFRelease(error);
}
```

I think I remember reading somewhere that this just magically works without the release, but can't find anything to verify that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory management of a CFErrorRef returned by ABRecordSetValue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627805/memory-management-of-a-cferrorref-in-core-foundation)

Comment: See the [Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-CJBEJBHH).  That function doesn't contain `Create` or `Copy` in its name, so you do not become the owner of any objects it returns.

Answer (score 3):

In CoreFoundation, if you get stuff back using a pointer, that's likely to have been allocated using one of the `...Create()` functions (doesn't the documentation say *anything* about this?), so you do have to release it.

In Foundation, the "returned" values are autoreleased, so there you don't need to (and in fact should not) do this.