# Casting a CFErrorRef to an NSError (or opposite) with ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I used to cast an NSError to CFErrorRef like this and using it in SMJobBless

```
NSError *error
BOOL removed = SMJobRemove(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd,
                               (CFStringRef) daemonBundleID,
                               auth,
                               true,
                               (CFErrorRef*) &error);
if (!removed) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to remove existing PacketTool");
        [NSApp presentError: error];
    }
```

As I've had errors with ARC, "Cast of an indirect pointer to an Obj-C pointer to 'CFErrorRef' is disallowed with ARC", I changed and decided to do the opposite

```
CFErrorRef *cfError = nil;
BOOL blessed = SMJobBless(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd, (__bridge CFStringRef)daemonBundleID,
                          auth,
                          cfError);
if (!blessed) {
    NSError *error = (__bridge NSError *)cfError;
    NSLog(@"Failed to bless PacketTool: %@", error);
    [NSApp presentError: error];
    return FALSE;
}
```

Now I've got an "Incompatible types casting 'CFErrorRef' to NSError *" with __bridge cast

What can I do?

Update: Thanks to Greg, correct code is now:

```
CFErrorRef cfError = nil;
BOOL blessed = SMJobBless(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd,
                          (__bridge CFStringRef) daemonBundleID,
                          auth,
                          &cfError);
if (!blessed) {
    NSError *error = (__bridge NSError *)cfError;
    NSLog(@"Failed to bless PacketTool: %@", error);
    [NSApp presentError: error];
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you declare cfError you shouldn't use pointer *, you should use:

```
CFErrorRef cfError = nil;
NSError *error = (__bridge NSError *)cfError;
```

In the other way it works like that:

```
NSError *error = nil;
CFErrorRef ref = (__bridge CFErrorRef) error;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: NSError *error = (__bridge NSError *)cfError; gives me an error "Incompatible types casting 'CFErrorRef*' to NSError * with a __bridge cast"

Comment: You forgot to add a pointer. It should be NSError *error = (__bridge NSError *)cfError; not NSError error = ...;

Comment: The error I've put was with the pointer, so it's still the same error, did you test it and was successful?

Comment: This works for me, I just tested it. Can you update your question with the new code and error?

Comment: Are you required to always explicitly initialize the `CFErrorRef` to `nil`?

Comment: @bcattle Yes, all CF objects should be explicitly initialized opposed to NS objects default `nil` or `0` initialization.

Comment: Actually you should transfer error object to ARC: `NSError *error = (__bridge_transfer NSError *)cfError;` as CF returns errors as retained objects (like create/copy rule). See sources for proof. @Greg @Tom

Answer (score 14):

On Dec 7 '13 at 16:05, Tom added:

> Update: Thanks to Greg, correct code is now:
>
> ```
> CFErrorRef cfError = nil;
> BOOL blessed = SMJobBless(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd,
>                           (__bridge CFStringRef) daemonBundleID,
>                           auth,
>                           &cfError);
> if (!blessed) {
>     NSError *error = (__bridge NSError *)cfError;
>     NSLog(@"Failed to bless PacketTool: %@", error);
>     [NSApp presentError: error];
>     return FALSE;
> }
> ```

I know that this post is 2 years old but it is wrong and I don't want other programmers copying that wrong code. **This code leaks memory as the CFError is never released!**

CoreFoundation has no automatic memory management, also not when using ARC. ARC only applies to Obj-C objects. And CoreFoundation doesn't know *autorelease* or *autorelease pools*, so CoreFoundation objects (`CFStringRef`, `CFNumberRef`, `CFErrorRef`, etc.) you get from CoreFoundation functions are never autoreleasing. They either don't need to be released at all or it's up to you to release them. And in case of out errors (`CFErrorRef *`), it's up to you to release them.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/8628267/15809

The first part of the code is correct:

```
CFErrorRef cfError = nil;
BOOL blessed = SMJobBless(
    kSMDomainSystemLaunchd,
    (__bridge CFStringRef)daemonBundleID,
    auth, &cfError
);
```

But then you need to understand bridge casting. The simplest form or bridge casting is just `__bridge` and this cast tells ARC "don't do anything". If you do this

```
NSError * error = (__bridge NSError *)cfError;
```

You tell ARC: "Cast `cfError` to `error` **but don't manage the memory of error after the cast, it's none of your business.**"

If you do this, you are still responsible for releasing the `CFErrorRef`! That means once you are done with `cfError` **and** with `error` ("and" as both point to the same object and if that is destroyed both pointers become invalid), you must do this:

```
CFRelease(cfError);
```

Otherwise you are leaking memory!

Alternatively you can tell ARC to manage the memory for you but then you need a different cast. If you cast like that

```
NSError * error = (__bridge_transfer NSError *)cfError;
```

you tell ARC: "Cast `cfError` to `error` **and then its up to you to manage the memory of `error`.**"

Now you don't need to release anything since as soon as `error` goes out of scope, ARC will release it for you. And because `error` and `cfError` are in fact the same object, releasing `error` also releases `cfError`, so now you don't need to release anything. As the name implies, this cast "transfers" the object to ARC. Once that is done, you must not use `cfError` at all any longer as you cannot say for sure when exactly ARC will release `error` and as soon as it does, `cfError` is an invalid pointer, using it can easily crash your whole app.

Same holds true if you cast into the other direction. If you do

```
NSError * error = ...;
CFErrorRef cfError = (__bridge CFErrorRef)error;
```

ARC will still manage the memory of `error`, which is dangerous as, see above, when ARC decides it can destroy `error`, `cfError` will also become invalid. It is okay if you only use `cfError` in the current scope, but if your `CFErrorRef` needs survive regardless what ARC does, then you do this cast:

```
NSError * error = ...;
CFErrorRef cfError = (__bridge_retained CFErrorRef)error;
```

This tells ARC: "**Retain `error` once**, then cast `error` to `cfError` **and don't ever balance this initial retain.**"

So even when `error` goes out of scope, it won't be released by ARC as the retain counter of the object won't become 0, it will still at least be 1 because of that cast. It's now up to you to take care of memory management and that means once you are done with `cfError`, you must release it:

```
CFRelease(cfError);
```