# Incompatible pointer types passing retainable parameter of type 'SecTrustResultType *'

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native, stripe-payments

I'm using `react-native-payments` library for ApplePay and getting below error I don't know what to do, any help please?

```
iOS: 16.4
Xcode: 14.3
react-native: 0.71.4
react-native-payments: 0.8.4
Deployment target: 14.0 in Xcode
```

**PPOTSimpleURLConnection.m file**

```
        NSString *domain = challenge.protectionSpace.host;
        SecTrustRef serverTrust = [[challenge protectionSpace] serverTrust];

        NSArray *policies = @[(__bridge_transfer id)SecPolicyCreateSSL(true, (__bridge CFStringRef)domain)];
        SecTrustSetPolicies(serverTrust, (__bridge CFArrayRef)policies);
        SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(serverTrust, (__bridge CFArrayRef)self.pinnedCertificateData);
        SecTrustResultType result;

//        OSStatus errorCode = SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &result);
        OSStatus errorCode = SecTrustEvaluateWithError(serverTrust, &result);

        BOOL evaluatesAsTrusted = (result == kSecTrustResultUnspecified || result == kSecTrustResultProceed);
        if (errorCode == errSecSuccess && evaluatesAsTrusted) {
            NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:serverTrust];
            completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);
        } else {
            completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeRejectProtectionSpace, NULL);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's Objective-C, not Swift. And I guess your error is on `OSStatus errorCode = SecTrustEvaluateWithError(serverTrust, &result);`, you should pass a `NSError` parameter, not a `SecTrustResultType`. Call later ` SecTrustGetTrustResult` is error is not nil. See the doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/2980705-sectrustevaluatewitherror?language=objc

Comment: Yes you're right @Larme I got the issue of type right? but I created it  but still gives error that  and this one ```Passing 'NSError' to parameter of incompatible type 'CF_RETURNS_RETAINED CFErrorRef  _Nullable *' (aka 'struct __CFError **')```

Comment: Sorry, `CFError`, is "old" `NSError`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427104/casting-a-cferrorref-to-an-nserror-or-opposite-with-arc but there should be bridgeable.

Comment: Now I've updated all the code and create ```CGError error;``` and passed it to ```OSStatus errorCode = SecTrustEvaluateWithError(serverTrust, *error);
``` but getting this ```Indirection requires pointer operand ('int32_t' (aka 'int') invalid)```